# Why is PHP explode keeping the \n?

Tags: php, explode, line-endings

Under Linux, I'm submitting a form containing text with `\n` as the line ending. That's the HTML:

```
<form id='frmTxt' autocomplete='off' method='post' action='index.php'>
    <p>Paste your text:</p>
    <textarea name='txt'></textarea>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>\n";
```

EDIT: In PHP, I do:

```
$txt = explode("\n",trim($_POST['txt']));
foreach ($txt as $t) {
    $words = explode(' ',$t);
    foreach ($words as $w) {
        echo "$w ";
    }
}
```

In the source code, after submitting a small text, I get:

```
Desde agosto não caía uma gota de chuva em Santiago. Ainda bem que nas torneiras — oh, leitor carioca, meu semelhante e meu irmão! — a água é abundante e limpa, e jorra à vontade para que à tardinha todo honesto cidadão possa regar suas plantas. Só na Inglaterra há gramados como no Chile, tão verdes, tão macios, tão perfeitos e lindos; o chileno trata o capim como se fossem flores.
 Numa tarde vagabunda de sábado andei passeando pelo parque Balmaceda, cheio de árvores, crianças, flores e namorados. Não é proibido, felizmente, pisar na grama. É proibido colher flores e jogar bola, mas isso representa mais uma opinião das placas da Prefeitura que uma realidade humana. Aqui e ali três meninos jogam bola e uma garota colhe flores sem que o guarda, por esse motivo, perca seu bom humor. Também já fumei duas vezes no ônibus, ignorando o aviso, e ninguém me chamou a atenção; Chile, graças a Deus, é um bom país latino.
 Mas falávamos de chuva; choveu. Choveu de tarde e a noite inteira, e o dia amanheceu enevoado. Depois o céu foi se limpando — e há três dias, enquanto a lua cresce, ele está azul, esplêndido, sem uma nuvem. Assim chegou o frio, ainda moderado, sem descer além dos 7 graus. Mas, com a chuva, o ar ficou mais fino e o alto cimo da Cordilheira se cobriu de neve.
 É difícil contar esse lado da paisagem, esse alto horizonte, essa imensa muralha azul toucada de neve que brilha ao sol. Quando o sol vai morrendo do outro lado do horizonte, a Cordilheira começa a mudar de cor — a Montanha se faz violeta, a neve às vezes tem reflexos púrpuros ou róseos, o azul do céu vai se fazendo mais grave no crepúsculo alto e solene.
 Santiago não tem mar; mas tem, a leste, essa presença de abismo e de infinito, essa paisagem de estranha força, pureza e paz — de uma oceânica beleza.
```

I only have one `\n` for each paragraph of the original text, so why do they remain in the array after calling the first explode?

EDIT2:

Now I understand it even less!

I copied the original file to Bless Hex Editor, and it shows a single 0A (\n) after each paragraph. PHP, however, outputs nothing inside the brackets for `echo "[".strpos($t,"\n")."]";` and numeric positions for `echo "[".strpos($t,"\r")."]";`.

Did my computer just went nuts or is it me?

PS: Now Bless just crashed... :(

Comment: You want `$txt = explode("\n", trim($_POST['txt']));`

Comment: Where do you see `\n` in the output?

Comment: `print_r()` puts newlines between each array element by itself, they're not in the values.

Comment: @Phil Why trim? There's no space after the period in the end of each paragraph, nor in their beginning.

Comment: I meant to eliminate that last, empty array item. I thought that's what your question was regarding

Comment: @Barmar Indeed! I got confused because I usually watch print_r results on the formatted page, not in the source code.

Comment: In the formatted page you wouldn't see newlines at all, since the browser wraps lines.

Comment: @Phil Just edited the question.

Comment: @Barmar Just edited the question.

Comment: Are you sure the lines aren't separated by `\r\n` in the original text?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, just used Geany's "Convert and Set to LF (Unix)", but it already displayed `mode: LF` in the status bar of the original text.

Comment: Look at your output with a hex editor.

Comment: Try doing `echo strpos($t, "\n");` in your loop to determine whether there's a `\n` actually there

Comment: @apokryfos It found nothing. But `echo strpos($t, "\r");` did. So Geany is not identifying `\r` as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and run this regular expression:

```
$txt = preg_split('/\r\n|\n|\r/', $_POST['txt']);
```

Should work, no matter what environment your input is coming from

[Here's a fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d00929a7f208385a9f54fadd85182d15b45952d)

Comment: Thank you, but right now I'm on a Linux machine, so my problem should not happen. I still have `\n` in the end of each array element.

Comment: Just edited the question.

Comment: @Rodrigo Ino, you shouldn't still have an empty array element. Check the fiddle I shared in the answer.

Comment: The empty array element is not the matter.

Comment: Your solution solved the problem, but I still got ghosts on my machine. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the problem is here. If I take the same input:

```
<?php

$_POST['txt'] = <<<eof
Desde agosto não caía uma gota de chuva em Santiago. Ainda bem que nas torneiras — oh, leitor carioca, meu semelhante e meu irmão! — a água é abundante e limpa, e jorra à vontade para que à tardinha todo honesto cidadão possa regar suas plantas. Só na Inglaterra há gramados como no Chile, tão verdes, tão macios, tão perfeitos e lindos; o chileno trata o capim como se fossem flores.
Numa tarde vagabunda de sábado andei passeando pelo parque Balmaceda, cheio de árvores, crianças, flores e namorados. Não é proibido, felizmente, pisar na grama. É proibido colher flores e jogar bola, mas isso representa mais uma opinião das placas da Prefeitura que uma realidade humana. Aqui e ali três meninos jogam bola e uma garota colhe flores sem que o guarda, por esse motivo, perca seu bom humor. Também já fumei duas vezes no ônibus, ignorando o aviso, e ninguém me chamou a atenção; Chile, graças a Deus, é um bom país latino.
Mas falávamos de chuva; choveu. Choveu de tarde e a noite inteira, e o dia amanheceu enevoado. Depois o céu foi se limpando — e há três dias, enquanto a lua cresce, ele está azul, esplêndido, sem uma nuvem. Assim chegou o frio, ainda moderado, sem descer além dos 7 graus. Mas, com a chuva, o ar ficou mais fino e o alto cimo da Cordilheira se cobriu de neve.
É difícil contar esse lado da paisagem, esse alto horizonte, essa imensa muralha azul toucada de neve que brilha ao sol. Quando o sol vai morrendo do outro lado do horizonte, a Cordilheira começa a mudar de cor — a Montanha se faz violeta, a neve às vezes tem reflexos púrpuros ou róseos, o azul do céu vai se fazendo mais grave no crepúsculo alto e solene.
Santiago não tem mar; mas tem, a leste, essa presença de abismo e de infinito, essa paisagem de estranha força, pureza e paz — de uma oceânica beleza.

eof;

$txt = explode("\n", $_POST['txt']);
var_export($txt);
```

I get the same output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Desde agosto não caía uma gota de chuva em Santiago. Ainda bem que nas torneiras — oh, leitor carioca, meu semelhante e meu irmão! — a água é abundante e limpa, e jorra à vontade para que à tardinha todo honesto cidadão possa regar suas plantas. Só na Inglaterra há gramados como no Chile, tão verdes, tão macios, tão perfeitos e lindos; o chileno trata o capim como se fossem flores.',
  1 => 'Numa tarde vagabunda de sábado andei passeando pelo parque Balmaceda, cheio de árvores, crianças, flores e namorados. Não é proibido, felizmente, pisar na grama. É proibido colher flores e jogar bola, mas isso representa mais uma opinião das placas da Prefeitura que uma realidade humana. Aqui e ali três meninos jogam bola e uma garota colhe flores sem que o guarda, por esse motivo, perca seu bom humor. Também já fumei duas vezes no ônibus, ignorando o aviso, e ninguém me chamou a atenção; Chile, graças a Deus, é um bom país latino.',
  2 => 'Mas falávamos de chuva; choveu. Choveu de tarde e a noite inteira, e o dia amanheceu enevoado. Depois o céu foi se limpando — e há três dias, enquanto a lua cresce, ele está azul, esplêndido, sem uma nuvem. Assim chegou o frio, ainda moderado, sem descer além dos 7 graus. Mas, com a chuva, o ar ficou mais fino e o alto cimo da Cordilheira se cobriu de neve.',
  3 => 'É difícil contar esse lado da paisagem, esse alto horizonte, essa imensa muralha azul toucada de neve que brilha ao sol. Quando o sol vai morrendo do outro lado do horizonte, a Cordilheira começa a mudar de cor — a Montanha se faz violeta, a neve às vezes tem reflexos púrpuros ou róseos, o azul do céu vai se fazendo mais grave no crepúsculo alto e solene.',
  4 => 'Santiago não tem mar; mas tem, a leste, essa presença de abismo e de infinito, essa paisagem de estranha força, pureza e paz — de uma oceânica beleza.',
  5 => '',
)
```

As can be seen, the resultant output has no newlines at all. The only possible
issue is the trailing empty element, which can be fixed by running `trim` on
the input before splitting.

Comment: I tried to make a minimal reproducible example, but the problem persists. Later on I do a `$words = explode(' ',$t);`, being $t each element of $txt, and every final word still contains a `\n`.

Comment: Edited the question.